# How do save tcpdump monitoring container for later analysis

Tags: docker, wireshark, tcpdump

I am using below command to monitor a single container. How can I extend this so that I can save the the tcp dump for later analysis using WireShark.

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:<container_name> \
  nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tcpdump has an option to send raw captured packets to stdout, send it to a file on host:

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:<> nickolaka/netchoot tcpdump -w - > packets.dump
```

or wireshark directly

```
docker run -it --rm --net container:<> nickolaka/netchoot -i any -w - | wireshark -k -i -
```

Comment: With `-it` it did not work for me, but without it it works: `docker run --rm --net=container:<container> nicolaka/netshoot tcpdump -i any --immediate-mode -w - | /Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS/Wireshark -k -i -`